# Understanding classes 'self'

Tags: python, class, python-3.4, self

In the following example `employee` is not used in the `__init__` function, but we used it in the `add_employee` function calling `self.employee.append()`. 
Why is that? Why did we use `self.employee.append()` instead of `employee.append()` ? I thought we only use `self` for variables in the `__init__` function.

```
class Workers():
    employee = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.skills = []
        self.add_employee()

    def add_employee(self):
        self.employee.append(self.name)
        print('{} added to list'.format(self.name))
```

Comment: Try `employee.append()` you should get a NameError on `employee`

Comment: @cricket_007 I know, that's why I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `employee` object is a class variable, not an instance variable. This means it is shared across all instances of that class. You can access it with `classname.classvariablename` or `instancename.classvariablename`. If you reassign an instance's version of it with something like `instancename.classvariablename = newvalue`, that instance will have a new instance variable of that name that masks its access to the class variable with the `self` reference (i.e., you won't be able to do `instancename.classvariablename` to get the class variable), but other instances - and the class - will still be able to (i.e., `classname.classvariable` will still work, and `otherinstancename.classvariable` will still point to that class variable). The following example demonstrates this.

```
>>> class A:
...     l = []
...
>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> a.l
[]
>>> A.l
[]
>>> a.l = 3
>>> b.l
[]
>>> b.l.append(1)
>>> b.l
[1]
>>> A.l
[1]
>>> a.l
3
```

Answer (score 1):

`employee`, `__init__`, and `add_employee` are just attributes of the class `Workers`.

`employee` is an attribute being a list, and `__init__` is another attribute, being a method.

Also from the [def documentation](
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-funcdef):

> A function definition is an executable statement. Its execution binds the function name in the current local namespace to a function object (a wrapper around the executable code for the function).

so `employees` and `__init__` and all other methods are really the same: names in a namespaces.

See also 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects